# When calculating complexity: does a[0] + a[1] result in two array accesses, or only one?

Tags: java, time-complexity, complexity-theory

Say a is an array of integers.
1) Given the code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
   if(a[0] + a[1] == 0){
      ...
   }
}
```

Would this be of time-complexity ~2n or rather ~1n
Note: I'm using tilde-notation, not big-Oh notation. The constant does matter.

2)What about this code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
   if(a[0] == 0 && a[1] == 0){
      ...
   }
}
```

Would this be of time-complexity ~2n or rather ~1n

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Since the second one depends on whether the && is lazy (short-circuited), it's a perfect example of why upper bound analysis is usually used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first example, it **has** to be two array accesses. Accessing `a[0]` tells us nothing about `a[1]`. We need to do both accesses to perform the `+` operation. As the bytecode* shows us:

```
      10: aload_0
      11: iconst_0
      12: iaload
      13: aload_0
      14: iconst_1
      15: iaload
      16: iadd
```

`aload_0` pushes the object in variable 0 on the stack (`a`, in my case), then of course `iconst_0` pushes `0` on the stack, and we see an `iaload` to get an `int` from the array. Then we see the whole thing repeated for index 1, and then the addition.

In the second example, if `a[0]` is `0`, the `&&` short-circuits and `a[1]` is never loaded or tested, so the time required will vary depending on how often the `a[1]` is required.

---

* How I got that bytecode: I created an `E.java` file:

```
class E {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        foo(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 });
    }

    static void foo(int[] a) {
        int N = a.length;
        for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
           if(a[0] + a[1] == 0){
              System.out.println("Foo");
           }
        }
    }
}
```

then compiled it, and used `javap -c E` to see the bytecode.